# Set heatmap radius to field or attribute value in QGIS 3.18

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, heat-map

I'm using a heatmap to visualize the peak ground acceleration of a seismic event. Each station coordinate has the peak acceleration value and a radius of influence of the zone. I'm trying to set the radius of each value heatmap to its field but I just can´t. I saw a Heatmap Plugin for QGIS 2.18 has advanced settings for assigning radius from a field, but it's not available for 3.18. Does anybody know a way I can do it?